# How to list all the installed scripts in deno?

Tags: deno

I had installed some scripts in deno before.

How do I list all the installed scripts in deno ?

Is there any deno subcommand to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

All downloaded scripts are stored in

```
$DENO_DIR/deps
```

`$DENO_DIR` varies depending on the OS

- On Linux/Redox:  `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno`  or  `$HOME/.cache/deno`
- On Windows:  `%LOCALAPPDATA%/deno`  (`%LOCALAPPDATA% = FOLDERID_LocalAppData`)
- On macOS:  `$HOME/Library/Caches/deno`  If something fails, it falls back to  `$HOME/.deno`

---

You can check the location doing:

```
deno info
```

Which will output:

```
DENO_DIR location: "/home/user/.cache/deno"
Remote modules cache: "/home/user/.cache/deno/deps"
TypeScript compiler cache: "/home/user/.cache/deno/gen"
```

---

The file is stored with a hashed name, so if you want to see the URL you'll need to access `{file}.metadata.json` and check `url` property.

You can use the following command to list all:

```
# Change /home/user/.cache/deno/deps with your location
find /home/user/.cache/deno/deps -name *.metadata.json | xargs jq ".url"
```

```
"https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/path/_util.ts"
"https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts"
"https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/http/_io.ts"
"https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/fmt/colors.ts"
"https://deno.land/std/fmt/colors.ts"
"https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/http/server.ts"
"https://deno.land/std/async/mux_async_iterator.ts"
"https://deno.land/std/testing/diff.ts"
```

Comment: I think the asker means the actual executables, which are in `$DENO_DIR/bin`

Comment: On Windows $DENO_DIR shows actually nothing. Related issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8361